# jQuery .slideToggle() hidden by default

Tags: jquery, hide, slidetoggle

I'm using `.slideToggle()`. I want to hide the element by default so I can slide them down on click.

I have that HTML code

```
<table>
  <tr class="master">
    <td class="entry">Hello</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="entry">Hello 1</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="entry">Hello 2</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="master">
    <td class="entry">Hello</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="entry">Hello 1</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="entry">Hello 2</td>
    <td class="entry">Kitty 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('.entry').hide(); // I also tried .slideUp
  $('.master').click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('tr.master').slideToggle(100, function() {
});});});
```

If I try to hide the entry class with `.hide()` or `.slideUp` I can't display it using `.slideToggle`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt this is your complete markup??? since you are using `.nextUntil` it will not hide the `tr.master` element it will try to find next sibling elements which are not `tr.master`

Comment: How can you click on it to display it if you've hidden the contents?

Comment: I simplified it in order to be easier to understand for now and for further consultation.

It's seems that changing $('.entry').hide(); by $('.master').nextUntil('tr.master').hide(); pretty much solves the problem

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Cnq7/1/

Comment: @Wistar added by answer back....

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'll accept it in 10 mins. Thanks.

Comment: @Wistar also when you simplify a problem, it still need to have all the relevant components of the question... in your sample it was not the case

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah I realized that so I made the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the non `tr.master` elements

```
$('.master').nextUntil('tr.master').hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Cnq7/)